# Is it possible to get the session value inside foreach?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->session->set_userdata('progress_counter',0);
foreach($data as $dta){ 
$ctr= $this->session->userdata('progress_counter')+1;
$this->session->set_userdata('progress_counter',$ctr);
}
```

I also have ajax  that check the session value every 1000ms when the user click the btton, the thing is i can't get the $this->session->userdata('progress_counter') thanks in advance

Comment: echo $this->session->userdata('progress_counter') ;exit; before foreach loop.check what you get

Comment: why am i going to exit @dhruvjadia, ?

Comment: just check value that you are storing in session variable after that you can remove exit

Answer (score 1):

Try like this....load `session` library first.

```
$this->load->library('session');

$this->session->set_userdata('progress_counter',0);
foreach($data as $dta){ 
$value = $this->session->userdata('progress_counter');
//echo $value; //check here
$ctr= $value + 1;
$this->session->set_userdata('progress_counter',$ctr);
}
```

Comment: if your array is empty it will not increment the value.so check first `print_r($data);`

Comment: it has a value already thanks @Hikmat Sijapati, the thing is i have a separate function(ajax) that call the $this->session->userdata('progress_counter'); while it is processing , is it possible

Comment: if you are making the ajax call with in the same `host` no any effect.

Comment: how am i able to do that ? do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 clearMe  = window.setInterval(function(){
  $.post("process.php",
  {

  },function(data){
    success:{
      console.log();
      // console.log(data+'/'+progress_index);
      $("#progess_ctr").html(data+'/'+progress_index);
      if(Number(data) == Number(progress_index) || Number(data) >= Number(progress_index)){
        clearInterval(clearMe);

        alert("successfully  finished.");
          location.reload();
      }
    }
  });
},1000);
```

> the progress_index is the total number data to be process 
>   this js that will run when the user click the button to catch the session value